# jQuery get nested XML list and publish as a HTML

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to get the items from xml list and print as a html page.
There is a small problem. You can see the problem here: http://daisy.unlu.co/handshake_api/.

There should be 2 lines I dont know why there are 6 lines. I print sku, description, price and image url. As you see variations have same image url, different price, different description and different sku.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<response>
    <objects type="list">
        <object type="hash">

            <imageURL>
                http://5387f51cd2471f8fea9a-807406182e5fe44c6ce394326aa32939.r89.cf2.rackcdn.com/image/189589cd5409c29b9efa1281d66b41bba0c101d6.jpg
            </imageURL>

            <variants type="list">

                <object type="hash">
                    <sku>IRIS3-1</sku>
                    <dimensions type="list">
                        <object type="hash">
                            <dimension>Dimension</dimension>
                            <value>Irish Spring Bar Soap-1 (3 x 3.75 Oz) x 18</value>
                        </object>
                    </dimensions>
                    <unitPrice>31.00</unitPrice>
                </object>

                <object type="hash">
                    <sku>IRIS3-2</sku>
                    <dimensions type="list">
                        <object type="hash">
                            <dimension>Dimension</dimension>
                            <value>Irish Spring Bar Soap-2 (3 x 3.75 Oz) x 18</value>
                        </object>
                    </dimensions>
                    <unitPrice>32.00</unitPrice>
                </object>

            </variants> 
        </object>
    </objects>
</response>
```

XML list

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $.get("items2.xml",{},function(xml){    
        // Build an HTML string
        myHTMLOutput = '';
        myHTMLOutput += '<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
        myHTMLOutput += '<th>SKU</th><th>Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th>';
        var mydata = " "; 
        var imageURL = " ";
        var sku = " ";
        var name = " ";
        var unitPrice = " ";


        $('objects object',xml).each(function(i) {
            imageURL = $(this).find("imageURL").text();
            //var sku;
            //var name;
            //var unitPrice;
            $(this).find('variants object').each(function(){

                sku = $(this).find("sku").text();
                name = $(this).find('dimensions object value').text();
                unitPrice = $(this).find("unitPrice").text();
                //console.log(unitPrice);
                mydata = BuildStudentHTML(sku,name, unitPrice,imageURL);
                myHTMLOutput = myHTMLOutput + mydata;
            });


            // Build row HTML data and store in string

        });
        myHTMLOutput += '</table>';

        // Update the DIV called Content Area with the HTML string
        $("#ContentArea").append(myHTMLOutput);
    });
});

function BuildStudentHTML(sku, name, unitPrice, imageURL){
   output = '';
   output += '<tr>';
   output += '<td>'+ sku + '</td>';
   output += '<td>'+ name +'</td>';
   output += '<td>'+ unitPrice +'</td>';
   output += '<td>'+ imageURL +'</td>';
   output += '</tr>';
   return output;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to utilize the direct child selector `>`: `$('objects > object')` when looping same-name nested nodes. This will select `object` nodes that are direct children of `objects`.

`$('objects object')` will select `object` nodes that are children of `objects` AND nested childeren of `variants` node. It's basically "give me all `object` nodes under `objects` nested or otherwise."

It's kind of hard to debug this without a working jsFiddle example so do not downvote me if it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to put into jsfiddle but somewhing went wrong with xml http://daisy.unlu.co/handshake_api.zip

Comment: Well, try putting `obejcts > object` in the first loop and `variants > object` in the second, see if it resolves your issues.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. Can you send me a link to read about variants > object

Comment: PLEASE ACCEPT my answer and read about different types of selectors here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/